# Css3 balloon animation

Tags: html, css

I've got a little bit problem here. :)
I try to made a good balloon animation with css3. [Link](https://codepen.io/Ben800/pen/bKdmNV)
My problem is I want the black line to stick the ground and just move the balloon with the black line a little bit. Like the wind blowing the balloons left and right :)

```css
 .container {
     width: 640px;
     height: 480px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 25%;
     top: 25%;
     background: url('mario_time.jpg') no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     cursor: crosshair;
     position: absolute;

 }
 
 .balloon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  left: 80px;
  -webkit-animation:inflatable 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation:inflatable 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  -o-animation:inflatable 6s ease-in-out infinite;
   animation:inflatable 6s ease-in-out infinite;
 }
 

.percentage {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: robot;
  font-size: 20px;
  color:  black;
  padding: 7px 25px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50px;
}

.score-box {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.score-box .label,
.score-box .percentage{
  visibility: hidden;
}

.welcome-box .ready {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: visible;

}


.score-box.ready {
  top: 20%;
}

.welcome-box.ready {
  top: 20%;
}

.score-box.ready .label,
.score-box.ready .percentage {
  visibility: visible;
}

.welcome-box.ready .badge {
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
  color: black;
  visibility: visible
}


.score-box.ready.ready .badge {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
  color: black
}

.label {
  font-family: roboto;
  font-size: 18px;
}


 
.balloon { 
  width: 38px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top:22%;
}
.balloon > div {
  width:100px;
  height:130px; 
  border-radius:0;
  border-radius:80% 80% 80% 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  padding:10px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center; 
}
.balloon > div{
  background: rgb(30,144,255);;
  left: 0; 
  -webkit-animation:balloon1 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation:balloon1 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  -o-animation:balloon1 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation:balloon1 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  &:before { 
   color: rgba(182, 15, 97, 0.9); ;
  }


}
.balloon > div:before {
  color:rgb(30,144,255);
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-11px;
  left: 52px;  
  content:"▲";
  font-size:1em;
}
.balloon > :after {
 display:inline-block;
 top:153px;
  top:167px;
  position:absolute;
  height:180px;
  width:3px;
  margin:0 auto;
  content:"";
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
  left: 60px;
  pointer-events: none
}

/*BALLOON 1 4*/
@-webkit-keyframes balloon1 {
  0%,100%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(0) rotate(-6deg);}
  50%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(0px) rotate(8deg); }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Baloon_shooter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class ="container">  
        
    <div class="balloon" style="left:50px">
      <div class="balloon1"></div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="balloon" style="left:150px">
     <div class="balloon2"></div>
    </div>
        
        
    <div class="balloon" style="left:250px">
     <div class="balloon3"></div>
    </div>
        
        
    <div class="balloon" style="left:350px">
     <div class="balloon4"></div>
    </div>
        
        
     
    <div class="score-box">
      <div class="badge">
        <span class="label">Gratulálunk, az ön nyereménye:</span>
        <div class="percentage">0</div>
      </div>
    </div>
   
        
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
 .container {
     width: 640px;
     height: 480px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 25%;
     top: 25%;
     background: url('mario_time.jpg') no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     cursor: crosshair;
     position: absolute;

 }
 
 .balloon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  left: 80px;
  -webkit-animation:inflatable 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation:inflatable 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  -o-animation:inflatable 6s ease-in-out infinite;
   animation:inflatable 6s ease-in-out infinite;
 }
 

.percentage {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: robot;
  font-size: 20px;
  color:  black;
  padding: 7px 25px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50px;
}

.score-box {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.score-box .label,
.score-box .percentage{
  visibility: hidden;
}

.welcome-box .ready {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: visible;

}


.score-box.ready {
  top: 20%;
}

.welcome-box.ready {
  top: 20%;
}

.score-box.ready .label,
.score-box.ready .percentage {
  visibility: visible;
}

.welcome-box.ready .badge {
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
  color: black;
  visibility: visible
}


.score-box.ready.ready .badge {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
  color: black
}

.label {
  font-family: roboto;
  font-size: 18px;
}


 
.balloon { 
  width: 38px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top:22%;
}
.balloon > div {
  width:100px;
  height:130px; 
  border-radius:0;
  border-radius:80% 80% 80% 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  padding:10px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center; 
}
.balloon > div{
  background: rgb(30,144,255);;
  left: 0; 
  &:before { 
   color: rgba(182, 15, 97, 0.9); ;
  }


}
.balloon > div:before {
  color:rgb(30,144,255);
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-11px;
  left: 52px;  
  content:"▲";
  font-size:1em;
}
.balloon > :after {
 display:inline-block;
 top:153px;
  top:167px;
  position:absolute;
  height:180px;
  width:3px;
  margin:0 auto;
  content:"";
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
  left: 60px;
  pointer-events: none;
        -webkit-animation:balloon1 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation:balloon1 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  -o-animation:balloon1 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation:balloon1 6s ease-in-out infinite;
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom; 

}

/*BALLOON 1 4*/
@-webkit-keyframes balloon1 {
  0%,100%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(0) rotate(-6deg);}
  50%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(0px) rotate(8deg); }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Baloon_shooter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class ="container">  
        
    <div class="balloon" style="left:50px">
      <div class="balloon1"></div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="balloon" style="left:150px">
     <div class="balloon2"></div>
    </div>
        
        
    <div class="balloon" style="left:250px">
     <div class="balloon3"></div>
    </div>
        
        
    <div class="balloon" style="left:350px">
     <div class="balloon4"></div>
    </div>
        
        
     
    <div class="score-box">
      <div class="badge">
        <span class="label">Gratulálunk, az ön nyereménye:</span>
        <div class="percentage">0</div>
      </div>
    </div>
   
        
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I use my css like this above, I can move the black line correctly, but I cant move the balloons like I want to :/.

Comment: [Here you go !](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50637409/9674579)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe this is what you want ?

Not exactly what you wanted, but a bit similar (without graphics),
possibly, you will have  to tune it according to your needs :)

```css
:root {
  --swings: calc(60 / 10 * 2s);
  --swing-time: var(--swings);
}

.balloon {
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  left: -10px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 80% 80% 80% 80%;
  width: 30px;
}

.stick {
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  top: 40px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  float: left;
  height: 70vh;
  background: black;
  width: 8px;
  animation: swing var(--swing-time) ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes swing {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-6deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(8deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="stick">
  <div class="balloon">
  </div></div>
<div class="stick">
  <div class="balloon">
  </div></div>
<div class="stick">
  <div class="balloon">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="stick">
  <div class="balloon">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's the same for me :) I want to work like this: https://codepen.io/psimyn/pen/KzxKgP the end of the line still in the ground,